# Создание таблицы в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

Есть вопрос, можно ли создать такую таблицу в Qt 5.

При этом в 3 колонке(col3), для всех ячеек у которых данные типа int, нужно добавить QSpinBox. Возможно ли реализовать такое. Если да, то как и какие лучше классы использовать?
Всё это нужно реализовать с QTableView, не QTableWidget.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172415/qcombobox-and-qspinbox-in-qtablewidget-with-appropriate-alignment

Comment: `QTableView`, `QAbstractTableModel`, `QStyledItemDelegate`

Comment: void QTreeWidget::setItemWidget(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column, QWidget *widget)

Comment: @PavelGridin В целом у меня всё получилось, крому одного. Как присвоить QComboBox, только одной ячейке, а не всей таблице или только строке/столбцу??
Если нужно к этому же вопросу могу приложить код

Comment: @KristapsTunnis, надо в createEditor() проверять index.column() и index.row(), для нужных возращать QComboBox, а для остальных `QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index)`